# safe way to get the country from an IP Address in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multilingual

I am working on multi language website , I can get Users IP Address, the problem is that I am looking for a very safe and trustworthy way to get IP and give me the country code , I want users confront their own language page while entering to my website, I have using once before, but it stops providing the service .  Does any one have any idea how to do it? here is my code , and I really appreciate any help. I am looking for a real trustworthy one , google or some other API or even any code suggestion

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {


        try
        {
            string userIpAddress = this.Request.UserHostAddress;
            var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https:// `I need API HERE` ")
            };

            var response = await client.GetAsync(userIpAddress);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var result = (Response)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response)).Deserialize(new StringReader(content));
            var country_name = result.CountryName;
            var country_code = result.CountryCode;
            TempData["Country_code"] = country_code;
            TempData["Country_name"] = country_name;

            if (country_code == "FR")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("fr", "Home");
            }
            else if (country_code == "JP")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("jp", "Home");
            }
            else if (country_code == "DE")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("de", "Home");
            }

            else if (country_code == "NL")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("nl", "Home");
            }
            else if (country_code == "CN")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("cn", "Home");
            }
            else if (country_code == "DK")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("dk", "Home");
            }
            else if (country_code == "RU")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ru", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("en", "Home");

            }


        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("en", "Home");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use IP addresses for this. It's not a good fit for the problem. For example, what if an English user takes their laptop on holiday with them, and uses your website from a different country? They would presumably still want to view the site in English, but you'll end up serving the content to them in a different language.

Instead, use the [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) request HTTP header:

> This header is a hint to be used when the server has no way of determining the language via another way, like a specific URL, that is controlled by an explicit user decision.

### An Example

```
StringWithQualityHeaderValue preferredLanguage = null;
if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Accept-Language"))
{
    preferredLanguage = Request.Headers["Accept-Language"]
        .Split(',')
        .Select(StringWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse)
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.Quality.GetValueOrDefault(1))
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

if (preferredLanguage?.Value == "fr")
{
    return RedirectToAction("fr", "home");
}
// Check for other languages.    
// ...
// If no redirects match, default to English.
return RedirectToAction("en", "home");
```

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh No, it just indicates the languages the user's browser has said it will accept. It's typically configured by the region the of the user's install. For example, my browser will always send `en` as a value, to indicate my browser is willing to accept UK English as my language. As an example, if the header specified in the request was `Accept-Language: de`, you'd know to redirect to the German version of your website.

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh I've added an example. You'll need to make sure to use the right language codes when doing the comparisons.

Comment: thank you for the knowledge. so you meant Accept-Language is what users have chosen in their setting of their browser?just let me work and know more about it.

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh Yes, although it's usually that the language has been set when the browser was installed. Some people do add other languages though. For example, if you are using Firefox, you can go to Options -> General, scroll down to Language and change the settings there. Those settings are what get sent in the `Accept-Language` header. Example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiXxN.png

Comment: its fine, but my question is that how some websites like godaddy.com change the language of whole website, for example if I connect with France ip with francaise or if I connect with german ip it shows me the whole website in german language. I want to implement something like godaddy.com

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh It could just be that your HTTP referer is from google.fr or google.de, and from checking that, you're redirected to a different language. Either way, the correct way to do it is to follow the user's preferences, not what an IP address tells you.

Comment: and another question please, should I do any changes in my global.asax file?

Comment: any way it helps me a lot . very very much. thank you 100..0000 times